# Why this global array is returning NULL from a callback function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, settings-api

This drove me crazy for hours now... Please tell me why the $ppk_fields array is empty in the ppk_field_callback function? Note that it returns the correct values in the ppk_default_id function but that is not a callback function. Thank you!

ppk.php

```
class Ppk {

    public function ini() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_ppk_p_menu' ) );
    }

    public function add_ppk_p_menu() {
        add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'PPK PLUGIN', 'PPK PLUGIN', 'manage_options', 'ppk_p', array( $this, 'ppk_build_dashboard' ) );
    }

    public function ppk_build_dashboard() {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'ppk-builder.php';
    }

}

if ( class_exists( 'Ppk' ) ) {
    $ppk = new Ppk();
    $ppk->ini();
}
```

ppk-builder.php

```
$ppk_sections = [
    'section_1' => [
        'title' => 'Group One'
    ]
];

$ppk_fields = [
    'field 1' => [
        'title'   => 'Fieald One',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'section_1',  
        'default' => 'default'
    ]
];

register_setting( 'ppk-builder', 'ppk-builder', 'ppk-builder_validate' );

    foreach ($ppk_sections as $id => $value) {
        add_settings_section( $id, $value['title'], 'ppk_section_callback', 'ppk_p');
    }

    foreach ($ppk_fields as $id => $value) {       
        add_settings_field( $id, $value['title'], 'ppk_field_callback', 'ppk_p', $value['section'], $id );
    }

function ppk_section_callback() {return null;}

function ppk_default_id( $id ) {
    global $ppk_fields;

    return $ppk_fields[ $id ]['default'];
}

function ppk_field_callback($id) {
    global $ppk_fields;

    $option = get_option('ppk-builder');
    $id_field = isset($option[$id]) ? $option[$id] : ppk_default_id($id);

    switch ($ppk_fields[$id]['type']) {
        case 'text':        
            echo '<input type="text" name="ppk-builder[' . $id . ']" value="' . $id_field . '"/>';
        break;
    }
}


settings_fields( 'ppk-builder' );
do_settings_sections( 'ppk_p' );
```

Comment: Where do you set the `$ppk_fields` variable as a global?

Comment: @TomJNowell inside the `ppk_field_callback` function, no where else. Why is it even when it's set as global i can't access the array values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you never created `$ppk_fields` as a global variable.

```
$ppk_fields = [
    'field 1' => [
        'title'   => 'Fieald One',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'section_1',  
        'default' => 'default'
    ]
];
```

Here we have a variable that is created normally, and obeys normal scoping rules. It isn't a global variable, and nobody has stated it's a global variable.

Further down the file we have:

```
function ppk_field_callback($id) {
    global $ppk_fields;
```

But, the global variable `$ppk_fields` is undefined, nobody defined it. You have to declare the variable as a global every time you use it, and that includes creation and destruction. No exceptions.

So you need to:

- declare that the variable is a global when you define it using `global $ppk_fields`

#### Doing it Wrong

But there's an even bigger problem. The biggest problem is that you used global variables at all. Global variables are a great way to avoid structuring your program, break unit tests, and introduce unnecessary complexity

For example, the global variables would be unnecessary if you'd placed all of the above code inside a class. Then, `$this->fields` would be what you'd use.

Here's a partial example:

**ppk_settings.php:**

```
class PPK_Settings {
    private $sections;
    private $fields;

    function __construct() {
        $this->sections = [
            'section_1' => [
                'title' => 'Group One'
            ]
        ];
        $this->fields = [
            'field 1' => [
                'title'   => 'Fieald One',
                'type'    => 'text',
                'section' => 'section_1',  
                'default' => 'default'
            ]
        ];
    }

    function register() {
        register_setting( 'ppk-builder', 'ppk-builder', 'ppk-builder_validate' );

        foreach ($this->sections as $id => $value) {
            add_settings_section( $id, $value['title'], array( $this, 'section_callback' ), 'ppk_p');
        }

        foreach ($this->fields as $id => $value) {       
            add_settings_field( $id, $value['title'], array( $this, 'ppk_field_callback' ), 'ppk_p', $value['section'], $id );
        }
    }

    // etc... other methods go here
}
```

**usage:**

```
require_once( 'ppk_settings.php' );    
$settings = new PPK_Settings();
$settings->register();
```

You could instead go the OO way, and have `PPK_Field` and `PPK_Section` objects, so that you can define your fields, then loop over the array creating objects, with no problems or troubles accessing them, and no need for globals or member variables

Comment: Didn't thought i could build this into a class since the file is required in another class method! Yes, it seems I can and this is way easier and better for me. Thank you so much for looking into my issue :)